# Is it possible to create non-existing properties in child components in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, react-children

I need to define some properties dynamically in child components of a tree (which do not support such properties), for the purpose of applying e2e tests, but I don't know if this is possible and how to do it in react

*Example*

We define our components normally, and our parent component creates a clone (I think this would be the only way this can be done) of its children, and adds the desired property

**Application**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const RadioGroup = ({ onChange, selected, children }) => {
  const RadioOption = React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
    return React.cloneElement(child, {
      onChange,
      checked: child.props.value === selected,
      dataTestId: "some-value" // new property here
    });
  });
  return <div className="RadioGroup">{RadioOption}</div>;
};

const RadioOption = ({ value, checked, onChange, children }) => {
  return (
    <div className="RadioOption ">
      <input
        id={value}
        type="radio"
        name={value}
        value={value}
        checked={checked}
        onChange={(e) => {
          onChange(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <label htmlFor={value}>{children}</label>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>How did you hear about our company?</h1>
      <RadioGroup onChange={setSelected} selected={selected}>
        <RadioOption value="Option 1">Option 1</RadioOption>
        <RadioOption value="Option 2">Option 2</RadioOption>
      </RadioGroup>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and would expect this to be the html generated after rendering

**Expected HTML output**

```html
<div class="App">
    <h1>How did you hear about our company?</h1>
    <div class="RadioGroup">
        <div data-test-id="some-value" class="RadioOption ">
            <input id="Option 1" type="radio" name="Option 1" value="Option 1">
            <label for="Option 1">Option 1</label>
        </div>
        <div data-test-id="some-another-value" class="RadioOption ">
            <input id="Option 2" type="radio" name="Option 2" value="Option 2">
            <label for="Option 2">Option 2 </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, obviously the example above does not produce this result, and I don't know how to do it and if there is a possibility for this.

**in short, it needs an approach where it would not be necessary to change the components themselves, as I do not have access to them**

> FAQ: **Why don't you just change the child components to accept this property (`dataTestId`) from their parents?**
>
> Because I have no control over some of these components, they are defined in a third-party library

I appreciate any and all help
thanks

Comment: by property do you mean an HTML attribute? Why do you need to change the components anyway? I don't think that trying to change components you don't own is a good idea

Comment: @ferrouskid

**1 - by property do you mean an HTML attribute?**
       yes, you would need an attribute that is exposed in the HTML

**2 - After all, why do you need to change the components?**
       I would like to add a property (html) so that my e2e tests could have a more appropriate selector property (very bad and inconsistent today, a data-test-id would be ideal to solve the problem)
[...]
I agree that I shouldn't change components that I don't have access to, but here it would be an advantage, improving the environment for the test engine (positive tradeoff)

Comment: I've had a similar issue a while ago that I solved by programmatically [adding data attributes](https://medium.com/gitconnected/programmatically-set-data-attribute-in-react-with-typescript-d256a2df712a) - but then again that's on components I owned. Maybe you could add `id` or `data` attributes to components that you do own - to help you narrow down your search?

Comment: Technically there's nothing stopping your from running client side JS script that finds the element that you need and adding the desired attribute to it, but that seems more hassle than help